# Batch combining sequential order files 1,2,3,4 into 1+2, 2+3, 3+4, 4+5

Tags: audio, audio-editing

I have a few thousand audio files named 1 2 3 4 5.
I want to combine them as follows:

- 1+2 → single new file
- 2+3 → single new file
- 3+4 → single new file
  etc. to the end

Can anyone please suggest a piece of software that has this capability for me? It wouldn't be feasible timewise to do manually.

Comment: By _1+2_, do you mean concatening the two files or summing them ?

Comment: I meant adding the the second audio file to play at the end of the first audio file -> and this to take the form of a single new file rather than 2 separate ones. Apologies but not sure if that means summing or concatening.

Comment: That's concatening